# spark-shell unable to start

Tags: scala, apache-spark

tried everything on the net but it still doesn't work

[Kindly help by checking the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no0oQ.png)

[environment variables path defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY3sa.png)

The error is:

````
```C:\Spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell
The system cannot find the path specified.
````

**EDIT**

Thanks for visiting, I solved it by adding SCALA_HOME in env variables and by avoiding putting \bin in the path defined for JAVA_HOME

Comment: Please help me with this as this is creating quite a lot problem

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code or error messages, copy-paste instead.

Comment: I'll do that right now

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should not include the `\bin` suffix, which should instead be specified in `PATH` (i.e. `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`).

Comment: That indeed i did, Appreciate the effort of helping others :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd C:\spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin` before running `spark-shell`

Comment: Appreciate the help, but it didn't work, it took some time to show the error though if it helps

Comment: Make sure your Java path is in the PATH environment variable

Comment: I've checked it twice, Appreciate the help, you can check the picture attached , it clearly shows that

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME contains spaces due to "Program Files". Try to use JAVA_HOME without spaces in path.

Comment: Okay let me check that , Appreciate the help

Comment: Appreciate your help brother, but defining all the paths again worked for me and adding %SCALA_HOME%